# Window App store > new project WindowsRuntimeComponent for background is not working with WCF data service

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I want to create a background task for updating a GEO location every 15 mins.

I'm using a background task and a timer, when I have the location I want to update the db every 15 minutes.

The problem is in WindowsRuntimeComponent ( used for background task) is not support with WCF data services communication : answer is [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/b32c60f4-6556-4c4d-8bf6-e345eb4c666b/error-classes-must-either-derive-from-systemobject-or-from-a-composable-windows-runtime-class?forum=winappswithcsharp)

So I decided to create background task in the same project, but the run method is not firing

I took the same step for adding the background task, when I took new project WindowsRuntimeComponent,

```
public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance){
  BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
  updatelocation();
  deferral.Complete();
}
```

How should I add a background task without creating a new project?

Comment: I am unsure of what your problem is exactly. Can you show code from the `updatelocation` method, and describe what kind of error you get?

Comment: Hi, my problem is , i want to use WCF data service in WindowsRuntimeComponent( new project i added for background)

Answer (score 3):

I think you should make a timer base event on app launch page. Which will affect all the time when your app is in running. And it will definitely work.
I used same for xaml C# based store app. And also you can add a configurable parameter in setting charm if user want to change the =refresh time then he/she can.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer, lets say if user locked the screen? or close the app, i would like to update Geo location , even if user close the app.

Comment: what you had suggest me , is already i did, but my question is very different :)

Comment: Ya I got your point. I think you have to declare background task in package manifest.I also answer again with a screen shot.

Comment: Mihir Problem is , we cannot add WCF data service reference inWindowsRuntimeComponent Project, which we will use for background runner

Comment: Can somebody here help me with this problem ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20708957/c-sharp-metro-xaml-designing-the-page-for-any-of-the-screen

Answer (score 1):

You can use WCF web service in background task. Try below given code.

```
public sealed class TestClass : IBackgroundTask
{
    void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        updatelocation();
        deferral.Complete(); 
    }
}

public IAsyncOperation updatelocation()
{
    return updatelocationHelper().AsAsyncOperation();
}

private async Task<string> updatelocationHelper()
{
    var wcfClient = new MyWcfClient();
    var content = await wcfClient.updatelocationAsync(wcf_service_url_here);

    return content;
}
```

Comment: strange my friend, i got service and i added reference, it's starting to show me an error!

Comment: Windows Runtime class 'WindowsRuntimeComponent1.ServiceReference1.THA001_devEntities' has an invalid base type, 'System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext'.  Classes must derive either from System.Object or from a composable Windows Runtime class.  Implementation inheritance is not allowed.

Comment: try delegate there. just code all background stuff in that delegate.

Answer (score 1):

As you have seen you cannot add a service reference to a Windows Runtime Component project.

What you have to have is an intermediate dll - create a new Windows Store *class library* project, and then add the WCF service reference there. Then in your Windows Runtime Component (your background task project), add a reference to the Windows Store class library.

Your references should look something like this:

Windows Store App --> Background task project --> Windows Store Library project --> WCF Service

You *might* also need to reference the library project from your application - try the above references - if you get a build error, then add this reference:

Windows Store App --> Windows Store Library project

You should now be able to make the WCF calls inside of the background task.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Add background task in app Manifest]

Register particular background task in manifest. I think it will work for all senario.

Below is link which will useful

[Its about background Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh977056.aspx)

[Its about how to define it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh977059.aspx)

[this will help you to understand data limit and all](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh977056.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Mihir, I know this stuff very well :)

Comment: do you ever used any web service in background task project ?

Comment: ya I worked on this but in diffrent manner.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/05/24/being-productive-in-the-background-background-tasks.aspx Try this link